# Can you move textures from different resourcepacks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried moving the textures by just coping and pasting, but it's not letting me move it to the other pack. I know you are just going to tell me to use WinRAR but my friend has done it without using WinRAR. The two packs I'm using are equanimity and hotdog 2.0. I just want the diamond axe and sword textures from equanimity other than that hotdog 2.0 all the way!

Comment: how do you mean by; not letting me move it to the other pack? Are there any dialogs that appear?

Comment: You say you don't want to use WinRAR, but do you have *any* decompression software? (WinZIP, 7Zip, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resource packs can be in both the format of a zip file or a folder in the resourcepacks folder. WinRAR is not required but if the resource pack is in the format of a zip file you will need a decompression program, WinRAR for example.

To copy a texture from one pack to another pack, open the folder of the pack, navigate to the texture you want and copy it from one pack to the same location in the other resource pack.

If you are in game you may have to reload the resources which can be done by either pressing F3 + R or going to the resource pack menu and clicking "Done".

Comment: ... Or you could use the one natively built into Windows Explorer. It lets you edit on the fly (without having to decompress, edit then re-compress).

Comment: @aytimothy Humm, not a windows user, never knew windows had one built in...

Answer (score 0):

You should drag the selected textures to your home screen then remove the same textured item from the opposite pack finally drag the original textures on the home screen to the resource pack that you removed textures from, thus making room for the preferred textures